# deleting a project in vs2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

How can I delete a project in VS 2008?
I am new to the C# / MS.Net development arena.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to delete a **Solution** -- Go to "My Documents", find the "My Visual Studio Project" (or smth) folder, and inside the subfolder of the project you want to delete. Delete it :>

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it from the solution using Visual Studio - select in Solution Explorer and press the Delete key, or right click and delete. To actually delete the project from your disk you will need to use Windows Explorer rather than Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?

If you have a solution with multiple projects, and you no longer need one of the projects, you can right-click on it and click Remove.  This will remove it from the solution but will not physically delete any files.

If you want to permanently delete a project and *all of its contents*, you can delete the project's directory in Windows Explorer.  First, make sure that you don't need any of the files.

If you're using source control see the documentation for your source control system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that it's a project in a multi-project solution.

If that's the case, just select the project in the Solution Explorer and either hit <kbd>Del</kbd> or right click and select **Remove** from the context menu.

You can then delete it from your hard drive using Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean with 'delete a project' ?
You can right-click on the project in the solution explorer, and choose 'Remove'.
The project will then be removed from the solution, but, it won't be removed physically from disk.

But, you can also choose to 'unload' a project from the solution.  The project will still be part of the solution, but it won't be compiled, until you reload it.

Comment: my bad. I meant how to delete a solution. I was able to delete my project (as described by ChrisF), but the solution is still there. Is the solution deleted from Windows explorer?

Comment: Yes, as it is just a bunch of files that are grouped toghether (described by the sln file).

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project in the solution explorer and select remove.

[alt text http://www.pickaloo.com/photos/01-10-10/53493.jpg](http://www.pickaloo.com/photos/01-10-10/53493.jpg)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to delete a project from Start Page? Delete it from the Hard Drive and click the project on the Start Page again and hit yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about removing a project from a solution, you can either delete it by right-clicking the project and select "Remove". This will physically remove the project from the drive as well as (obviously) remove it from the current solution.

You can also right-click the project and select "Remove" which will remove the project from the solution, but not from physical storage, so the project will still be available, but not attached to the current solution.

EDIT:

For solutions, simply delete them from your physical drive and then, if the solution still shows up in the recent projects list, you can edit the registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\ProjectMRUList) and remove the item there.

Comment: What's the diffrence between the two solutions you describe? Am i missing something very obvious(that is very possible)? If deleted solutions/projects show up in the recent list, just try to open them and VS asks if you want to delete it (from registry i guess.)

Comment: Indeed, that is my experience too. I've heard that sometimes some solutions remain in the list despite VS prompting for their removal. Never seen it myself though.